# Filesystem (file, folder) with display order

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, relational-database

I want to design like os file system, 
with specific display order (sequence) can be update.

I want file and folder can be same layer, 
file doesn't have to inside a folder.
But in below design, if the file not in any folder I don't know how to save the sequence, save in where??

Any suggestion will be apperciate

data example

```
folder(id:1)      top layer: sequence: 0
  file(id:1)                 sequence_in_folder: 0
  file(id:2)                 sequence_in_folder: 1
folder(id:2)      top layer: sequence: 1
  file(id:3)                 sequence_in_folder: 0
file(id:4)        top layer: sequence: 2 << **sequence save in which table ??**
file(id:5)        top layer: sequence: 3 << **sequence save in which table ??**

folder
id  sequence  parent_folder_id
1   0
2   1

file
id  sequence_in_folder  folder_id
1   0                   1
2   1                   1
3   0                   2
4   ?????
5   ????
```

schema

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "folder"(
  "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
  "sequence" integer NOT NULL,
  "parent_folder_id" integer Default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "file"(
  "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
  "sequence_in_folder" integer Default NULL,
  "parent_folder_id" integer NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

**UPDATE**
base on @Laurenz Albe answer, no need change table design, 
just create a root folder.
but how to sorting data order by a field cross/exist in two table?
the sequence exist in folder table and file table, how to sort them together

query

```
SELECT * FROM folder fo 
  LEFT JOIN file fi ON fi.parent_folder_id = fo.id
WHERE fo.parent_folder_id = $1 AND fi.parent_folder_id = $1
  ORDER BY  fo.sequence fi.sequence ??   ;

[1]
```

data example

```
folder
id | sequence | parent_folder_id | name
1  | 0        |                  | root
2  | 0        | 1                | 
3  | 2        | 1                |

file
id | sequence | parent_folder_id |
1  | 1        | 1                |
```

output

```
folder(id:1, sequence:0 name:root)
  folder(id:2, sequence:0)
  file(id:1, sequence:1)
  folder(id:3 sequence:2)
```

Comment: what kind of problem with the sequence?

Comment: @ChrisTravers this design seems only work `bookmark` have to be inside `bookmark_folder`   bookmark.sequence = sequence in specific folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggestions:

1. Introduce an “anonymous” top folder that contains all the top level elements.
2. Rename the `sequence` column of `bookmerk_folder` to `max_sequence` or so to avoid confusion with `bookmark.sequence`.

Comment: thanks for reply, I can't get how to solve my question, would you provide some example code?

Comment: Well, there is a "root" `folder`, e.g. the one with `id = 0`. That's the one that contains top level items. Whenever you add a new element to a `folder`, you increase `folder.max_sequence` by one and use that number as `file.sequence`.

Comment: ... sorry I don't get it.    do you mean I have to create a root folder save in folder table first  and ..

Comment: Right. That corresponds to reality, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Supplemental to Laurenz's answer:

unify your bookmark and folder columns, maybe bookmark_node and require that everything have a parent which is not a bookmark.  Something like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fsnode(
  "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
  "name" text,
  "is_folder" bool,
  "parent_is_folder" bool not null,
  "sequence" integer NOT NULL,
  "parent_folder_id" integer Default NULL,
  CHECK (parent_is_folder),
  PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
  UNIQUE(id, is_folder), # needed for fkey below
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_folder_id, parent_is_folder) REFERENCES fsnode (id, is_folder)
);
```

Comment: thanks for reply, do you mean only one table? if `parent_folder_id` fk `id` , the root folder still can be null value? what is `CHECK (parent_is_folder)` does that mean if `parent_is_folder == false` not accept insert ??

Comment: Right, all rows have to have parent_is_folder to true.  But the foreign key for parent_folder_id can still be null.  That;s to prevent bookmarks from also being folders.

Comment: if `parent_folder_id` can be null  also can be in reference does that mean if I want to delete, just do something like `delete from .. where id = ..` , all sub related rows will automatic recursive delete,  don't need to use this https://jsfiddle.net/L934gyo7/ recursive query?

Comment: you can do that by making the foreign key ON DELETE CASCADE but that is a separate discussion.

Comment: I get it, I will use this, Thanks so much!!